# Inverse Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, data-transformation, inverse-problem, normalizing-flow

Suppose there is a series of transformation applied to the random variable $z_0$ such that

$$
z_M = f_{\theta_{M}} \circ f_{\theta_{M-1}} \circ \ldots \circ f_{\theta_{1}}(z_0) =: f_{\theta}(z_0).
$$

Additionally, these transformations $f_{\theta_k}, \ k = 1,\ldots,M$, are all diffeomorphisms, meaning they are invertible and both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

Suppose this network of *finite* transformations is trained such that the KL divergence between $p_M(z_M;\theta)$ and some *desired* distribution $p_{M}^*(z_M)$ is minimized, i.e.,

$$
\theta^* = \textrm{argmin}_{\theta} \ L(\theta) := \mathbb{D}_{\textrm{KL}}\left[p_M(z_M;\theta) \ || \ p_M^*(z_M)\right].
$$

Given these optimal parameters $\theta^*$, and since it is guaranteed that $f^{-1}$ exists, I am interested in computing the inverse function at some sampled point $z_M$.
Since this is a composition of $M$ different transformations, there is no analytical way to compute the inverse, but I was wondering if there may be numerical techniques. Thank you!

Comment: Neural networks have usually multiple inputs producing single output, another reason for being non-invertable.

Comment: There are invertible models, e.g. normalizing flows. I'm curious why you think it's _not_ possible in those cases to compute the inverse at a given point.

Comment: Tim - I'm considering normalizing flows, in which the maps are invertible.
@Arya - Since I have many transformations, it's not possible to calculate the inverse analytically such that given some $z_M$, I get $z_0 = f^{-1}(z_M)$. That's why I was wondering how do I compute the inverse at all!